# Googlebot cannot access 'maps.googleapis.com' and '.js'. Is this preventing my site from getting indexed in Google search?

Tags: javascript, fetch-as-google, map, block, render

When I fetch and render it is showing partial. It looks fine. The same way Google sees it is the same way visitors see it. But 'maps.googleapis.com' and '.js' are showing blocked. But I didn't blocked that in robots.txt.

Is this preventing my site from listing in Google search?